# Wrong discretization hist2d

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, histogram

I need to build bi-dimentional distribution using X and Y.

I used plt.hist2d, np.histogram2d and scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d, but they all returned the wrong distribution

The point's pairs designed so that A-beams value always bigger or equal to B-beams value. But on the imshow the distribution cloud is below the line A=B, which is totally incorrect

How can I fix that? The is no problem with data

A_beams=[3,6,9,12,4...]

B_beams=[2,4,5,9,2...]

Code I used

```
matrix=scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(a_beams, b_beams,None,'count',bins=50)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(151)
im1 = ax1.imshow(matrix, interpolation=None,norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r)
```

[image]

Comment: 0-30 are your bin numbers, not the bin values.  All the functions you are using return the bin values so you should use those to set the extent of the image or use in pcolormesh as the x and y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

To build such bi-dimentional distribution we need to use function plt.hist2d, not the scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d

```
matrix,_, _,_ = plt.hist2d(a_beams,b_beams,bins=bins)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(151)
im1 = ax1.imshow(matrix, interpolation=None,norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r)
```

[correct bi-dimentional distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BsGP.png)